# Where can I go to recieve feedback on web design projects?

Tags: website-design, education, critique

Are there are any web design forums where designers can submit their work to receive feedback and advice? I am looking for a place that I can seek advice on how to improve my designs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Reddit.com/r/design_critique](http://reddit.com/r/design_critiques)

The subreddit's not bad for critique, but you have to take it with a grain of salt. There are definitely professionals that like to pitch in, but it seems like you'll have two or three professional (appearing) feedback responses, for every five or six students, amateurs, or print designer's who will pitch in on a web design critique, because the subreddit's meant for all mediums. That said, it's still never bad to receive any extra feedback and judge with your own knowledge and experience. Any comments that are from real ammateurs, nonprofessionals, or nonweb designers generally stick out.

There's also a web design subreddit that probably has a cleaner demographic, but you might be told to move your post over to the design critique category.

As far as other sources, I'd be interested in finding out. There are graphic design forums all over the place, but as with many things, large user content generated sites are taking over, so I haven't found any as active as reddit.

Answer (score 10):

You could also try [Behance](http://www.behance.net/).  It is a free board you can post your portfolio and search for inspiration.  Ask for input when you post your images.

Another option is [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/).  Post up some work there and you can get an all around type review structure.

A good idea would be to also go to a forum.  There are some links below:

1. [estetica-design-forum](http://www.estetica-design-forum.com/graphic-design-web-design-critique/)
2. [digitalpoint](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/forums/html-website-design.16/)
3. [graphicdesignforum](http://www.graphicdesignforum.com/forum/forum/graphic-design/the-crit-pit)
4. [ucreative](http://www.ucreative.com/forum)
5. [designforums](http://www.designforums.co.uk/forum/27-graphic-design-logo-design-critique/)
6. [designerstalk](http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/showcase/)
7. [webdesignforums](http://www.webdesignforums.net/forum/general-web-design-discussion/)
8. [Please critique me](http://www.pleasecritiqueme.com/)
9. [Five Second Test](http://fivesecondtest.com/)
10. [Concept Feedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/)
11. [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)

PAID:

1. [User Testing](http://www.usertesting.com/)
2. [Usabilla](https://usabilla.com/)

Invite:

1. [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/)

Graphic Design Stack Exchange allows critiques if you follow the [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).

If you're active in the community you could always look for your local [meetup](http://www.meetup.com/) and if you dont find one you can always start one.

Answer (score 8):

[Hunie](http://hunie.co/) and [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/) are two fantastic communities for feedback and critique--however, they're both invite only and can be difficult to get into if you are a new designer.

As suggested above, [Behance](http://www.behance.net/) and [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/) are also good communities, though their size makes it a bit hard to "break through" and get solid feedback. That being said, they are public and anyone can register.

For web design, a service I've used in the past is called [Five Second Test](http://fivesecondtest.com/), though this is largely about user testing and not so much about design critique.

Another good service, totally forgot about it, is [conceptfeedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/) and I would suggest giving it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

If it's web design feedback you're after then things like Behance and DeviantArt are ok but they're more geared towards graphics. I'd suggest going onto the Envato forums, probably the [themeforest forum](http://themeforest.net/forums) as the users on there are all people who are selling websites so they're all looking for feedback themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [TrackDuck Visual Feedback tool](https://trackduck.com). It has an option to collect anonymous feedback. All you have to do is to provide a link. People would be able to mark particular areas of your website and leave comments.